# How to add new row on existing formArray ? Angular

Tags: javascript, html, angular

On this form I need to add new row and remove row? How to do

```
  editCity() {   
    this.form = this.fo'',))),
      recepieType:
  } 

 createForm() {

this.form = this.formBuilder.group({
});
```

}

I need to add function which is add new row or delete existing row.

Comment: Curiosity: why do you use a FormArray of FormGroups to only store a unique value? You can use a FormArray of FormControls

Answer (score 0):

Here is the method to add ingredient :

```
addIngredients() {
    let ingredientsCtrl = <FormArray> this.form.controls['ingredients']
    ingredientsCtrl.push(this.fb.group({ing: [null]}));
}
```

You can delete the ingredient(formGorup) using array index of the object

Here is the method to delete ingredient :

```
deleteIngredients(index: number) {
    let ingredientsCtrl = <FormArray> this.form.controls['ingredients']
    ingredientsCtrl.removeAt(index);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I recently implemented with a simpler and neat code:

HTML:

```
<div>
    <input *ngFor="let field of fieldArray; let i = index;" type="text" [(ngModel)]="fieldArray[i]"  >
</div>
```

TS:

```
fieldArray: Array<string> = [];
newAttribute: string = "";


addMoreRows(type:string){

        this.fieldArray.push(this.newAttribute);
        this.newAttribute = "";


    }
```

***Your formArray is fieldArray here. This might not be the exact code you need, but off course you can take the lead from here, if helpful.

I didnt use form builder etc. stuff.
newAttribute is just an empty filler placeholder.

Comment: The question is about Reactive Forms (not about Template driven Forms)